# Ошибка функции iqTest()

Tags: javascript

В IQ тесте дается массив с числами.
 Одно из них отличается от других четностью/нечетностью.
Функция возвращает его индекс.

```
function iqTest(str) {
    array = str.split(' ');
    var boolArray = [];
    function checkEven(num) {
        return +num % 2 === 0? true:false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        boolArray.push(checkEven(array[i]));
    }

    var differ = boolArray[0];
    var index = 1;

    for (var j = 1; j < boolArray.length; j++) {
        if (boolArray[j] !== differ) {
            differ = boolArray[j];
            index = j;
        }
    }
    return index;
};
```

Но функция возвращает неверный индекс, когда отличный от других елемент - четное число

Comment: откуда взялась переменная `diff`? `if (boolArray[j] !== dif)`

Comment: Не по вопросу: 1. Конструкция `? true : false` в данном случае бесполезна. 2. Не нужно ставить `;` после `for {}` и `function {}`, а вот после `return`-ов и других строк внутри блоков кода нужно.

Comment: Наверно глобально dif == 1 вот и работает только с нечетными.

Comment: я назвал её диффер после, в коде правильно написано

Comment: А что должно возвращаться для таких массивов: `[1, 2]`, `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, `[1, 3, 5, 7]`?

Comment: @Yaant, такие массивы не подходят под задачу: _**Одно** из них отличается от других четностью/нечетностью._

Comment: @Grundy: Это понятно, что не подходят. Вопрос в том, как на них должна реагировать функция?

Comment: @Yaant, без разницы, задача искусственная, следовательно можно считать что вход всегда удовлетворяет задаче.

Comment: Почему ? true:false безполезна

Comment: @wan140, потому что до `?` и так выражение возвращающее `true` или `false`, и это значение совпадает с тем, что ты возвращаешь

Comment: И что мне делать?

Comment: если уберешь отсюда: `+num % 2 === 0? true:false;` -> `? true:false` то ничего не поменяется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как можно решить задачу, не сравнивая четность каждого элемента массива с четностью предыдущих:

1. Создаём два массива: один для хранения индексов четных чисел, другой - для нечетных
2. Проходим по проверяемому массиву и добавляем индекс элемента в соответствующий массив
3. Если в каком-то из массивов ровно один элемент - возвращаем его, иначе - например, -1

Реализация:

```js
function iqTest(array) {
  var data = [[], []];
  array.forEach(function(value, index) {
    data[value % 2].push(index);
  });
  if (data[0].length == 1)
    return data[0][0];
  if (data[1].length == 1)
    return data[1][0];
  return -1;
}

console.log(iqTest([1, 3, 5, 2]));
```

---

При желании можно расширить алгоритм для проверки остатка от деления на произвольное (заданное) число:

```js
function iqTest(array, base) {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < base; i++)
    data.push([]);
    
  array.forEach(function(value, index) {
    data[value % base].push(index);
  });
  
  for (var i = 0; i < base; i++) {
    if (data[i].length == 1)
      return data[i][0];
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(iqTest([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3));
```

Comment: Хороший вариант. Не додумался до этого. Спасибо!

Comment: Только нужно, чтобы индекс начинался от одного. Ну это я сам исправлю,